# Angular2 Typescript how to wait for eventlistener before sending data to view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Fairly new to angular2 typescript and stumbold uppon this problem:

I'm making a online song playlist with HTML Audio player, whenever I press the play button I want to get the duration of the song. Here lies the problem.

**How do I access the class variable duration and how can I make the view get updated whenever the listener is done.**

Here is how my class looks like :

```
duration:any = '0:00';
audio = new Audio();
```

Getting the duration of the song :

```
clickPlayMusic(event:any):void {
                this.audio.ondurationchange = function() {
                    XXXX = this.duration; 

                };
}
```

Thanks for reading,

Kind regards

Comment: can you pls pose more details about your problem ?

Comment: If you just want to show updated duration then use interpolation i.e. {{duration}}, otherwise please provide more detail for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have a  {{duration}} in my template html but the problem is, whenever I press my play button on webpage an event clickPlayMusic is triggered. It will will play a song and also return the duration of the song to my class variable duration. But I'm unable to access the class variable as I'm working in the function  of the event listener which in my case is ondurarionchage.  The X X X X should be the class variable duration wjich I declared above.  But I'm unable to grab it. This is a scope issue I reckon